# Is there a way to correctly display image from post content in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm actually building my first blog in Gatsby with data from WordPress.

I stuck on a question : how to display correctly the image from WYSIWYG to Gatsby ?

For example, on [this page](https://mediakod.netlify.com/contact), one of two image correctly appear but not the second. Someone can explain me if this is possible to download allWpMedia in /static/ folder (like the default images) and replace all `<img />` to `<Img />` from `gatsby-image` ?

Thanks

**Version of my packaging**

Node@10.13.0
NPM@6.4.1
├── gatsby@2.13.32
├── gatsby-image@2.2.6
├── gatsby-plugin-manifest@2.2.3
├── gatsby-plugin-offline@2.2.4
├── gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts@1.4.2
├── gatsby-plugin-react-helmet@3.1.2
├── gatsby-plugin-sass@2.1.3
├── gatsby-plugin-sharp@2.2.8
├── gatsby-plugin-sitemap@2.2.3
├── gatsby-remark-images@3.1.7
├── gatsby-source-filesystem@2.1.5
├── gatsby-source-wordpress@3.1.10
├── gatsby-transformer-remark@2.6.8
├── gatsby-transformer-sharp@2.2.4
├── gatsby-wordpress-inline-images@1.0.0
├── html-react-parser@0.9.1
├── jsdom@15.1.1
├── node-sass@4.12.0
├── prettier@1.18.2
├── prop-types@15.7.2
├── react@16.8.6
├── react-body-classname@1.3.0
├── react-dom@16.8.6
└── react-helmet@5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Wordsby actually does this by default right now. https://github.com/TylerBarnes/wordsby

He also created a plugin called gatsby-wordpress-inline-images specifically for this issue.

https://github.com/TylerBarnes/gatsby-wordpress-inline-images